# HTML2Canvas error with prototype.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, html2canvas

Does prototype.js have no conflict like jquery? Because html2canvas is having a js error

this is the error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.getChildren is not a function
at html2canvas.js:2014
at prototype.js:297
at prototype.js:266
at Array._each (prototype.js:472)
at Array.each (prototype.js:264)
at Array.collect (prototype.js:296)
at NodeParser.getChildren (html2canvas.js:2012)
at new NodeParser (html2canvas.js:1860)
at renderWindow (html2canvas.js:1018)
at html2canvas.js:1005
```

Comment: can you provide some more context and the error message ?

Comment: Here is the error

Comment: Which versions of PrototypeJS / html2canvas ?

Comment: prototype.js - Prototype JavaScript framework, version 1.5.0_rc0 (c) 2005 Sam Stephenson <sam@conio.net>
html2canvas -   html2canvas 0.5.0-beta4 <http://html2canvas.hertzen.com>
  Copyright (c) 2016 Niklas von Hertzen